# how to convert date to age?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I want to calculate age from Y-m-d format which i have stored in database.How to pass the result of dob which is age in view.How to pass the stored Date in view in this format like age 20 years.

My View:

```
<th style="width: 10px;text-align: left">Age</th>

@if(count($members)>0)
@foreach($members as $key=>$member)
  <tr>
    <td>{{$key+1}}</td>
     <td>{{$member['dob']}}</td>
@endforeach
@endif
```

My Controller:

```
 public function index()
{
    $departments = [];

    $members = Member::where('status', 0)
        ->leftjoin('member_details', 'members.cnic', '=', 'member_details.cnic')
        ->leftjoin('districts','districts.dis_id','=','members.district')
        ->paginate(100,['members.*','member_details.*','members.id as id','member_details.id as memberid','district','dis_name']);

    for ($m = 0; $m <count($members); $m++) {
        $finalDep = [];
        $getDepartments = MemberInterestDepartment::where('cnic' , $members[$m]['cnic'])
            ->leftjoin('departments','departments.dep_id','=','member_interest_departments.department')
            ->get(['department','dep_name'])->toArray();
        if(count($getDepartments)>1){

                for($r=0; $r<count($getDepartments); $r++){
                    $finalDep[] = $getDepartments[$r]['dep_name'];
                }
        }else{
            $finalDep = $getDepartments[0]['dep_name'];
        }

        $departments[] = array(
            'id' => $members[$m]['id'],
            'cnic' => $members[$m]['cnic'],
            'name' => $members[$m]['name'],
            'district' => $members[$m]['dis_name'],
            'party_joining_year' => $members[$m]['party_joining_year'],
            'dob' => $members[$m]['dob'],
            'qualification' => $members[$m]['qualification'],
            'profession' => $members[$m]['profession'],
            'department' => $finalDep,
        );
    }
    $allDepartments = Department::all();

    return view('dashboard')->with(['pages' => $members,'members' => $departments, 'province' => $province, 'division' => $division, 'districts' => $districts, 'departments' => $allDepartments]);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Import in your controller

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

and then pass the dob value in parse

```
$dob = '1990/01/15';    
echo Carbon::parse($dob)->age .' years';
```

Here is how you can do it:

```
$departments[] = array(
            'id' => $members[$m]['id'],
            'cnic' => $members[$m]['cnic'],
            'name' => $members[$m]['name'],
            'district' => $members[$m]['dis_name'],
            'party_joining_year' => $members[$m]['party_joining_year'],
            'dob' => Carbon::parse($members[$m]['dob'])->age  .' years',
            'qualification' => $members[$m]['qualification'],
            'profession' => $members[$m]['profession'],
            'department' => $finalDep,
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure about that but i hope it will help 
Laravel use  carbon package to all the functions of the dates https://carbon.nesbot.com/

And Carbon has built in function `toDateString()` which will convert the timestamps like 
for eg suppose this is the record `1998-03-10 07:37:45` in table by using the function

```
toDateString ('1998-03-10 07:37:45')
```

The result will be in `Y-m-d format as(1998-03-10)`

After that
and add the tiny function to corresponding model

```
public static function carbonDatesToAge($toDateFormat)
    {
            $dateOfBirth = "$toDateFormat";
            $dateOfBirthToYear = new \DateTime($dateOfBirth);
            $todaysDate = new \DateTime();

        echo $todaysDate->diff($dateOfBirthToYear)->y;

    }
```

and Finally in your view file

Method one

```
<td>{{ App\Models\PersonalDetail::carbonDatesToAge($item->date_of_birth->toDateString()) }}</td>
```

use only if the method one fails

```
<td>{{ App\Models\PersonalDetail::carbonDatesToAge(Carbon\Carbon::parse($item->date_of_birth)->format('Y-m-d')) }}</td>
```

just change your model name to `Member` and use it in  view that's it

if you find any difficulties please comment below

enjoy!!!!